# Get the following Yearmonth

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

How would i get  202001 from

`@year = 2019 and @month = 12`

```
Where [yearmonth] = CONCAT(@Year, @Month) + 1
```

Comment: What is the data type of year month?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Where [yearmonth] = FORMAT(DATEADD(m, 1, DATEFROMPARTS(@year, @month, 1)), 'yyyyMM')
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=3563a36ecb68823e9a247dea0988baf0)

Comment: that make it 000202 i need 202001

Comment: You are correct. I was declaring the variable as varchar i forgot to put Varchar(255). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming these are numbers, you can use arithmetic:

```
where yearmonth = ((@year * 12 + @month + 1) / 12) * 100 +
                   (@year * 12 + @month + 1) % 12
                  )
```

If it is a string, you can convert.

Comment: that makes it 201. I need 202001

Comment: @TheRealHamzaYusuf . . . I changed the answer.  I misread the question.